# Puppet - how to set up a conditional to check if a package is installed and in case of not installed, I need to skipped it?

Tags: conditional-statements, puppet

Sorry but I'm starting my jorny in puppet and  I'm facing my first challenge with that tool.
I want to check in puppet if a package is insttalled on server and in case of yes, guarantee  it is running and in case of NOT installed, just skipped to the next task.

```
class profile::windows::rapid7 {
 
  $manage_rapid7  = lookup('manage_rapid7',         Optional[Boolean], 'first', true)
  $rapid7_filepath = 'C:\Program Files\Rapid7\Insight Agent\ir_agent.exe'
 
  $rapid7_service_exists = find_file($rapid7_filepath)
 
  if $facts['kernel'] == 'Windows' {
 
    if $manage_rapid7 {
      if($rapid7_service_exists){
        service { 'ir_agent':
          ensure  => 'running',
          enable  => 'true',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see above, in case of rapid7 is installed, I'll have sure it is running but now I have some servers that don't have this package and because of this, I'm getting error.
So my question is:
Is it possible to just skipp this task in case of this pkg isn't installed?

Best Regards,

Comment: This is not how a declarative language works. You would code the class to install the package and start the service, and then only apply the class to nodes that satisfy whatever conditions you have for wanting this software configured on that node.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check in puppet if a package is insttalled on server and in case of yes, guarantee it is running and in case of NOT installed, just skipped to the next task.

The most appropriate approach is for Puppet to know based on node identity whether the package is supposed to be installed.  This is the realm of [node classification](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/nodes_external.html), generally realized via [node blocks](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_node_definitions.html), via [external node classifier](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/nodes_external.html#writing-node-classifiers-external-node-classifiers), and / or via node-specific [external data](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/hiera.html).  Using these tools, you would inform Puppet during catalog building whether to apply the class that manages the service in question, with what class parameters.  It would be typical to also choose on the same basis whether to apply a class that manages the package itself.  You can find many examples of this approach on [the Forge](https://forge.puppet.com/).

But where you do need to feed data about the current state of a node into the catalog building process, the Puppet mechanism that serves is [*facts*](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/facter.html).  It would be possible to write a custom or external fact that tested whether the package was installed.  You could then write Puppet conditional statements to influence the contents of the node's catalog based on the value of that fact.  Note well, however, that this speaks to node state before the run, and also that it is superfluous if you want Puppet to manage the installation status of the package.